# Component defined in child route does not run NgOnInit lifecycle function

Tags: angular

My application is set up so that my main routes load template components, which they themselves have a router outlet in order to load in the specific component that I want to laod into that template:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'signup',
    component: Template1Component,
    children: [{ path: '', component: SignupComponent  }]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: Template1Component,
    children: [{ path: '', component: LoginComponent }]
  },
  {
    path: 'logout',
    component: Template2Component,
    children: [{ path: '', component: WelcomeComponent }]
  }
];
```

The current issue I am having is that the component that is loaded via the children property loads fine (the UI is instantiated). However, the NgOnInit function does not run and subsequently my signup form does not work properly.

Comment: Show please yours Component, maybe you forget to implement s OnInit

Comment: implementing the interface is a good practice, but isn't mandatory. make sure method name is `ngOnInit()` and not `NgOnInit` as you typed in your question.

Comment: Yes but if you correct implement it , it add hint about method name

Comment: ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Initalize signup component');
  }

Answer (score 0):

Check in yours component
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit

As

Interface helps us to avoid spelling and syntax mistakes.

You can try

```
   @ngModule({
       imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation:    ‘reload’})],
       exports: [RouterModule],
   })
```